# Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIControlEvents' to different enumeration type 'UIControlState' (aka 'enum UIControlState')

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicontrolevents

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and getting the following warning when trying to compile my objective C code:

```
**Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIControlEvents' to different enumeration type 'UIControlState' (aka 'enum UIControlState')**
```

The Warning is in `abcLabel.m`:

```
[searchBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:**UIControlEventTouchUpInside**];
```

Comment: you should use UIControlStateNormal (or other in UIControlState enum) instead of UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Comment: write a method for touchUpInside and change the searchBtn Color since there are no such selector for UIButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use UIControlState enumeration, for example:

```
[searchBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Option you can choose from:

```
enum {
   UIControlStateNormal               = 0,
   UIControlStateHighlighted          = 1 << 0,
   UIControlStateDisabled             = 1 << 1,
   UIControlStateSelected             = 1 << 2,
   UIControlStateApplication          = 0x00FF0000,
   UIControlStateReserved             = 0xFF000000
};
```

`UIControlEvent` you should use when you want to add events to the control, for example handle button press.

Comment: UIControlEventTouchUpInside and UIControlStateHighlighted are working same?

Comment: No they are not the same. This is taken from apple doc: UIControlEventTouchUpInside = 1 <<  6, but from my answer above UIControlStateHighlighted = 1 << 0. As you can see there are different.

Comment: So, What I write instead of UIControlEventTouchUpInside to solve the warning?

Comment: It's depend what you want your button to appear, but I believe you are after UIControlStateNormal.